# simple if brackets with or and boolean from function do not work

Tags: php

I'am new in PHP and I do not get this simple code to run:

```
if( !isset( $_COOKIE["itsmejoe"]) ||  !isBot()  ){
    echo "yes";
}else{
    echo "no";
};

function isBot(){
   return true;
}
```

If I change the isBot() output from true to false it shout gives yes or no.
In my example there is always a yes given.
Whats wrong?

Comment: it shout show "no" if isBot is true (independed the cookie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you want overall is for it to say yes if the cookie is set, unless `isBot()` is true, and "no" if the cookie is not set, regardless of whether or not `isBot()` is true. If that is the case, I think it simplifies things to use AND instead of OR.

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE["itsmejoe"]) $$ !isBot()  ){
    // requirements for "yes": cookie is set and isBot is false
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, you're passing true when `$_COOKIE["itsmejoe"]` is not set OR `isBot()` returns false.

When you change the output of `isBot()` to false, it will *always* return "yes".

Comment: thx for your answer. What I need is, if isBot is true it shout show "no" undepended the cookie.

Comment: if(  isBot() == true  ){
    echo "no";
}else{
    echo "yes";
};

function isBot(){
   return true;
}

Comment: @hamburger In that case replace OR operator with AND. Replace || with && and it will work like you want.

Answer (score 0):

When using the "!" operator it means that if one of the statements are false the whole statement is true. Bad coding practice in my opinion since it is overly complex without adding any value. Make the statement simpler to ease up understanding when things are not working.